# Open cart wrong image on product page

Tags: opencart

On the product page in the admin two images, and the site shows other. also contains the main picture is true.
admin
http://clip2net.com/s/joSghM
site
http://apolo.com.ua/?route=product/product&path=108_121&product_id=2032

where there may be a mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your sort orders to 1 and 2, where 1 is being the first one to display, and 2 is the 2nd one.

Comment: can you tell me where i must change this?

Comment: On the first picture you've posted, there's the picture on the left side, there's an editbox with a 0 in it in the middle, and a button on the right side. Change the top 0 to 1, and the bottom 0 to 2.